# Click function in Jquery not functioning while using it on computer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Been making this websites for a bit today as I've been getting back into making websites. I'm trying to use jquery and have even tried pure javascript to get this click button to work. I went through and copied and pasted the entirety of this pages code into jsfiddle and for some reason it refuses to work in my code but works just fine when I put it into jsfiddle.

So when you click the button on the top right, its going to give the div below a new class. You can see it works here in jsfiddle but for some reason it refuses to work in my copy on my computer.

My html page is correctly loading jquery because I've used .resize() already but it refuses to allow me to use any version of click in any way or form.

Does anyone have any insight as to what may cause this click function to stop working?

```
  // find elements
 var banner = $("#banner-message")
 var button = $("button")

 // handle click and add class
 button.on("click", function(){
   banner.addClass("alt")
 })
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nathanahartmann/a3s9zjk6/3/

Comment: You could be using preventDefault somewhere else in your code? That may do it

Comment: I just started this website, the javascript you see is all that I am currently running right now D:

Comment: Also - which browser? :)

Comment: I've tried it on chrome, firefox, and edge all with the same results, all up to date

Comment: this code actually works. in the jsFiddle

Comment: I know it does, but it wasn't working in my code I had on my computer, I ended up finding the fix, being just moving my javascript down below the body.

Answer (score 1):

Browser plugins? I know I've shot myself in the foot because my ad blocking or social media blocking plugins mess with frameworks and other java-script behavior.

Comment: only things that I am running is adblocker, it also doesn't work on edge or firefox which have no plugins.

Comment: actually I'm not even running ad blocker, I never reinstalled it since I reinstalled windows. I literally have no extra browser plugins running. It's just bare bones chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work fine now: [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/71hbac2p/)

You were missing a lot of ';'s throughout this function:

```
var banner = $("#banner-message");
var button = $("#rHotBar");

// handle click and add class
button.on('click', function(){
  banner.addClass("alt");
});
```

Similarly, you were referencing the image for `var button`, not the outer class, the click was registering on the outer div, not the image itself!  :)

Comment: didn't help unfortunately, I'm trying to run it on most up to date version of chrome and its not working

Comment: Ah, make sure that function is at the top of your `<script>` section & that all relevant jQuery sections end with a `;` ?

Comment: nothing, it's the weirdest thing. I'm not really sure why it's not working.

I've made plenty of websites in the past using the same exact code and for some reason in this one instance, it's not working.

Comment: Worth noting - also missing a `;` after the window.load event `}`

Comment: Ironically it throws no errors... which is weird... but I got it to work, turns out it was just referencing Jquery weird, the fix ended up being putting the reference to my javascipt after my body instead of in the header.

Answer (score 0):

Weirdest thing ever, It's where it's referencing Jquery in relation to my javascript. For some reason I just posted

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/javascript.js"></script>
```

a second time down below to see what it would do and for some reason it started working. Not really sure why it's doing this but it seemed to work for some reason. It's not referencing Jquery correctly somehow?

Comment: If you're building a website, I sincerely hope you took a good long look at react, Vue, angular, and blazor too.

Comment: I've looked at react and angular, This is just really fun to learn from scratch myself.